# Gogehat's question - clarity

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Gogehat's question [Why isn't there a closely related key to C minor that has D as tonic?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70531/why-isnt-there-a-closely-related-key-to-c-minor-that-has-d-as-tonic/75419#75419) is in question here.

At first his / her question was so unclear.  So a bunch of users began to guess Gogehat's intention and edit the post accordingly.  This only made it more and more unclear, so Some Guy came and rolled back the question, telling the editors to vote to close it instead.

Then these people voted to close Gogehat's post.  The post was closed.  Everything was all quiet afterwards.

However, some other users, like Richard, pretty much knew what the OP was actually asking.  In fact, I'll have to admit that I also got his / her intention, too.  So we began digging ourselves into the closed question and began editing the question in order to have it reopened.  While we were trying to improve the post, the users who voted to close didn't really seemed to have any focus on this.

A bunch of edits later, we have finally reached a question that everyone was able to understand, without conflicting with the OP's intention.  The close-voters also seemed quite impressed over our work.  Doktor Mayhem had reopened the question last month, and Gogehat looked happy, too.

---

I would like to compliment all users who joined with me to clarify the closed question, and I will also compliment Doktor Mayhem for reopening the post for us.  Thank you for all of you guys for the contribution, and even Gogehat, for asking a good question.  I would like to give thanks to the close-voters and Some Guy, as they also put efforts for improvement, too.

---

Now I have one question for Doktor Mayhem: **Why did you decide to reopen the question last month instead of reopening immediately after the question was clarified?**

Comment: Also, it often takes a while for posts to be reopened; users tend to interact with the re-openable questions only through the review queue (people VTC directly from questions, but people don't even go on closed questions very often), hence it takes longer, in my experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm unsure - this was a wee while ago.

I can only assume that is when I saw the updates and comments regarding the clarity improvements and agreed with them.

Maybe that was from a general scan through closed questions, maybe it was a comment or someone shared a link, or possibly a reopen vote made it visible.

For future reference there is no way that a question can be "reopened immediately after it was clarified" without something to trigger a reopen. Usually this requires reopen votes and consensus that it is fully clarified. So if you think an on-hold question has been brought to a state suitable for reopening, use your reopen vote.